# What Python command allows us export Maya model to USDA file format?

Tags: python, maya

Recently Pixar released a plugin for working with `USDA` file format in Maya. Also there's a USD API. With this API is easy to create a `usdPrimitives`:

```
from pxr import Usd, UsdGeom

stage = Usd.Stage.CreateNew('HelloWorld.usda')
xformPrim = UsdGeom.Xform.Define(stage, '/hello')
spherePrim = UsdGeom.Sphere.Define(stage, '/hello/world')
stage.GetRootLayer().Save()
```

And then execute this Python script to create a `.usda` file.

```
$ python extras/usd/tutorials/helloWorld/helloWorld.py
```

What Python command is used for export to a `USDA` file format?

Comment: Did you have a closer look at the Maya plugin wich comes with USD? There should be all necessary commands.

Comment: Sorry but I found no info on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin supports loading and saving of documents in USD format but not creating geometry or scenes programmatically.

[According to the docs](https://graphics.pixar.com/usd/docs/Maya-USD-Plugins.html#MayaUSDPlugins-UsdImport) for the plugins, the supported commands are `USDImport` and `USDExport`.   The flags for the commands are documented on the link.

`USDImport` and `USDExport` are only available if you have loaded the USD plugin with the UI or programmatically. You can  make sure the plugin is loaded with the `loadPlugin()` command from the `maya.cmds` module.  Once it's loaded, call `cmds.USDExport()` on your scene (the plugin will automatically register the import and export functions in `maya.cmds` when it is loaded)